# How to retrieve specific items from express-validator array?

Tags: node.js, express-validator

How can I just retrieve the `"msg"` object from `errors.array()`?

The output of the whole array looks like: `[{"value":"abc","msg":"Your email is not valid","param":"email","location":"body"}]`

I tried to specify the `"msg"` object with `errors.array()[1]` but it returned nothing.

```
  router.post("/signup",
  [
    check('email', 'Your email is not valid').not().isEmpty().isEmail().normalizeEmail(),
    check('password', 'Your password must be at least 5 characters').not().isEmpty().isLength({min: 5})
  ],
  function (req, res, next) {
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      res.render("user/signup", {
        hasErrors: JSON.stringify(errors.array()[1])
      });
    } else {
      //...
    }
  });
```

Error output in my static file:

```
<h2 style="color: red;">{{hasErrors}}</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.array()` or `.mapped()` if you want to access the errors. Otherwise you can use `.formatWith` as showed in the [`doc`](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-result-api.html#array-options):

```
app.post('/create-user', yourValidationChains, (req, res) => {
  // errors will be like [{ myLocation: 'body' }, { myLocation: 'query' }], etc
  const errors = myValidationResult(req).array();
});
```

Or, **formatWith**:

```
app.post('/create-user', yourValidationChains, (req, res, next) => {
  const errorFormatter = ({ location, msg, param, value, nestedErrors }) => {
    // Build your resulting errors however you want! String, object, whatever - it works!
    return `${location}[${param}]: ${msg}`;
  };
  const result = validationResult(req).formatWith(errorFormatter);
  if (!result.isEmpty()) {
    // Response will contain something like
    // { errors: [ "body[password]: must be at least 10 chars long" ] }
    return res.json({ errors: result.array() });
  }

  // Handle your request as if no errors happened
});
```

Comment: How can I write a custom error formatter in TypeScript?